# What is the little multi-colored icon above the mercenaries head?

Tags: diablo-ii

What is the little multi-colored icon above the mercenaries head in Diablo 2? I have noticed it appear during the middle of combat and it makes a weird noise when it happens to. **What exactly is happening with my mercenary at that time?**

Edit: Here is the screenshot, you can see one monster is dead and the other is right next to me. So it isn't anything to do with being cursed or anything I don't think. It appeared a good 5 times pretty quickly. When I said multi-colored in the first post, it looks like this is blue/green/white and it swirls around in a circle. I guess it isn't very *little*, my mistake.

[image]

Comment: Most likely a debuff going on, but without picture it's hard to tell.

Comment: In what location do you get it? I think that it might be a curse. A screenshot would help a lot

Comment: I will see if I can get a screenshot, it might be kind of hard since it appears and disappears kinda quickly. It happens pretty much anywhere, if I'm in a cave, field, dungeon, etc... but only during battle.

Comment: That isn't a debuff, its sure. In fact is some kind of self-buff your companion is using.

Comment: And it is not an icon either. :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the Diablo2 wiki [Diablo II wiki](http://www.diablowiki.com/Hirelings_%28Diablo_II%29), your companion, which is a rogue, is using Inner Sight and Fire/Cold Arrow only. So I guess it is the "Inner Sight" skill.

Comment: Yes, this graphic is inner sight. You can further demonstrate it by using the ability of the same name on the 'Amazon' class.

Comment: *Inner sight* is an active skill, not a passive. It decreases the Defense of all enemies in range (indicated by the little sparkles on *their* heads after she casts it).